# How to properly setup vscode with pyside? Missing suggestions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyside, pyside2

I'm very new to pyside, qt and python.
I managed to setup a project with a basic window and a push button which closes the app.
My problem is, that somehow vscode won't show all properties available, even though the code runs with them fine.
[image: vscode-pyside2-problem-1.png]
Note how a bunch of other properties are suggested, except for the signal `clicked`. If I hover over `clicked`, it tells me `clicked: Any`
Only during debugging, vscode tells me what clicked is:
[image: vscode-pyside2-problem-2.png]
Current setup:

- OS: Linux
- Virtualenv with `pyside2` installed
- Using `ms-python.python` and `ms-python.vscode-pylance`
- `ui/MainWindow.ui` file and corresponding generated `ui/MainWindow_ui.ui` file with `pyside2-uic`

Comment: Since you're new to pyside and Qt6 is still pretty new (some classes and features have even been temporarily removed, and there are some bugs here and there), I'd think about using PySide2 right now if I were you.

Comment: @musicamante I tested this exact setup except using pyside2 and the problem remains. Ill update the question. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately I don't use vscode, so I cannot help you on this. But consider that signals are not actual functions, they are objects that are bounded to the instances, which might be the reason for which they're not correctly recognized for the completion.

Comment: @musicamante I basicly followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JL0H2xLdu2k) tutorial and he seemed to have completion for `clicked`, thats why i was wondering why i dont got it. I have also no idea if this is the "right" way to do it, since i dont have experience. The only thing i can say is, that `clicked` is in fact a object and `clicked.connect()` a member functions (which also is not being completed).

Comment: @musicamante Im also not sure if this is a problem with vscode. I looked through the definitions and it seems like there arent any for `clicked`. I tried reinstalling pyside2/6 and it never popped up. In fact no field popped up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate the stubs manually by running

```
pyside6-genpyi all
```

PySide2 have the same tools, it's not just for PySide6.

***EDIT**: PySide2 didn't seems to have to same tooling, there's a new `pyside2-stubs` since May 21, 2022, https://pypi.org/project/PySide2-stubs/*

I use PDM to handle my project, with the last one I execute:

```
pdm run pyside6-genpyi all
```

And PyLance detect all my stubs:

[image]

If you got error with the `Signal`, it's because Qt/PySide do some magic tricks and convert `Signal` to `SignalInstance`. My solution is to cast `SignalInstance` to get to right hint.

```py
from typing import cast
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal, SignalInstance

class ConnectionPanel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    connected = cast(SignalInstance, Signal())
    disconnected = cast(SignalInstance, Signal())
```

Comment: Signal to SignalInstance, it is a real magic trick ==

Comment: I am currently recreating this issue, and I have noticed, that for pyside2 there is no genpyi. The instructions for pyside6 however work fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is possible that pyside2 didn't have the tool to generate stubs since it was released before pyside6 and the typing in python wasn't as popular as it is now. You could try `pyside2-stubs` maybe: https://pypi.org/project/PySide2-stubs/
Give us feedback if it works well.

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER**

This answer is wrong. It just explains the root of problem with default setup and does not offer a working solution. I was thinking it was right at the time of writing. But since a [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69976742/15469341) is offered, it should be the accepted answer instead of this one. I'm not deleting the post since some would find it helpful in historical manner

---

**Original post:**

Pylance tries to use **stub files**(which you can traverse with Go to definition) of PySide6 library to offer intellisense features. According to [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) `clicked` signal should be defined in **QAbstractButton** class but in type definitions (stubs) we can't see this signal definitions. If you look closely PyCharm gathers it from QAbstractButton class in your linked video but Pylance in Vs Code searches it in QPushButton.

This was a known issue in Pylance since PySide2 but according to the [Pylance repo](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/497#issuecomment-736960601) this may originate from *Qt for Python's incorrect type definitions:*

> Libraries that have typing that's either incorrect or doesn't work well with PyLance. Best and maybe most known example I have is PySide2 (but see issues with other libraries in earlier posts): tons(!) of errors for correct, working code, which makes spotting real errors difficult. The same code in PyQt5 (which is basically a twin sibling to PySide2) doesn't raise any complaints from PyLance, so I'm assuming the problem is with PySide2's typing. While I'm aware that neither PySide2's typing nor PyLance's analysis results are necessarily incorrect, fact is that most of the reported errors should not be present, so for sake of simplicity I'll just call it incorrect.

The reason it can access at runtime is; it's created instance over shiboken QObject type I guess. I don't have any workarounds but it doesn't bother me because I prefer following official Qt documentation when looking for which signals available in a class definition.

**EDIT:** There was a resolved [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1079) on this which is the reason PyCharm able to handle auto-completion. Opening another on VS Code should help.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It explained why switching to PyQt5 "solved" my Problem. Any idea which language server works with pyside2?

Comment: I've tried couple of them before - with no luck. But re-opening [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1079) bug report with vscode info should help. Because that is also shows how PyCharm able to do this :)

Comment: Hi @Sewbacca , I've recently noticed the other answer and updated mine. Can you unaccept my answer? see the disclaimer for details

Answer (score 0):

Since I had this exact same problem, I found this very informative comment on a PySide bug report: [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1603](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1603?focusedCommentId=572722&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-572722)

> Our stubs are auto-generated by introspection, signals are not included. At the moment, we need to discuss how we should support signals.

So, not a bug, just a missing feature.