# Get signature of a bound SignalInstance in pyside2

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I'm trying to find a way to get the signature of a bound `SignalInstance` in PySide.

Take the following example:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QObject

class MyObj(QObject):
    some_signal = Signal(int)

obj = MyObj()
sig_instance = obj.some_signal
```

I can get to the signature of `some_signal` if I have a pointer to `obj` or `MyObj` itself, with `obj.metaObject().method(5).methodSignature()` ... but what if I only had a pointer to `sig_instance`?

In C, the `SignalInstance` keeps the signature in a private struct `PySideSignalInstancePrivate` ([here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside2/libpyside/pysidesignal_p.h?h=5.15.2#n77)) ... but after a log of digging, I've been unable to come up with a way to recover that signature given only the python `SignalInstance`

tips?

---

**update:**

If it's genuinely not possible without access to the metaObject on `obj` itself.  I have this stupid solution... but still would love to know if there's a better way.

```py
try:
    sig_instance.emit(*(1,) * 50)  # emit with ridiculous args
except TypeError as e:
    print(str(e).split(' only accepts')[0])  # parse err
```

I'll also note that a `PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal` *does* have an attribute `.signal` that holds the string form of the signature

Comment: I don't think it's possible, anyway that information is in the QMetaObject of the QObject.

Comment: @tlambert may I ask you why do you need this?

Comment: sure, the "general" use case is providing `signal_instance.emit` as a callback to some other thing.  It would be nice if that other thing could inspect the signature of `signal_instance.emit` (exactly like Qt itself does if you use `connect(some_callback)`... Qt is able to be smart about not providing too many params to some_callback).  Unfortunately: `inspect.signature(sig_instance.emit)` gives `Signature (*args: typing.Any)`... not too helpful.
The specific use case is here: https://github.com/tlambert03/psygnal/issues/47

Comment: @tlambert Yes, I found the same issue in PySide too. Maybe you could file a bug report on Qt?

Comment: sure, can do.  Almost started there, but then chickened out and came here :)

Answer (score 1):

I give this solution in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69976742/9788069).

If you got error with the Signal, it's because Qt/PySide do some magic tricks and convert Signal to SignalInstance. My solution is to cast SignalInstance to get to right hint.

```
from typing import cast
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, SignalInstance

class MyObj(QObject):
    some_signal = cast(SignalInstance, Signal(int))

obj = MyObj()
sig_instance = obj.some_signal
```

Comment: thanks, but this isn't a typing issue.  I have an application where I'd like to know the number of parameters that `some_signal` expects (i.e. 1 in this example).  but without having access to `MyObj` or `obj`